# InstanceClass.NewInstance vs InstanceClass.Create

Tags: delphi, oop, vcl

what different between  InstanceClass.NewInstance+Instance.Create and InstanceClass.Create;

Method1:

```
Instance := TComponent(InstanceClass.NewInstance);
Instance.Create(Self);
```

Method2:

```
Instance := InstanceClass.Create(Self);
```

Which is better?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would always use `InstanceClass.Create` if it is appropriate – and invariably it is.

There are plenty of reasons. A very good one is that the single line version is more concise. Another is that the single line version is the standard, commonly used approach.

Yet another reason is the handling of exceptions in the constructor which your method 1 does not manage correctly. In case of an exception, the new instance will be destroyed, but the instance variable has still been assigned to. That's an important difference from method 2 and goes against all the lifetime management conventions of Delphi.

You mention `TApplication.CreateForm`. Let's take a look at it:

```
Instance := TComponent(InstanceClass.NewInstance);
TComponent(Reference) := Instance;
try
  Instance.Create(Self);
except
  TComponent(Reference) := nil;
  raise;
end;
```

Remember that `Reference` is the form variable that you pass as a `var` parameter. The point about this is this code assigns that form variable before calling the constructor. Normally that assignment is only made after the constructor completes.

Presumably this is so that code which references the form variable (often a global variable) can work even if it is invoked from inside that form's constructor. This is a very special case and is overwhelmingly the exception rather than the rule. Don't let this special case drive your mainstream coding style.

Comment: It is interesting to know why valid form variable is required before form constructor ends?

Comment: @Serg I think it's bogus. It's probably a relic from very early VCL. It seems flawed to use a reference to a partially constructed object. I would not view this as good style. I think it's just legacy.

Comment: Definitely that is not a good style, but forms have special role in VCL and IDE itself, so there may be a serious reason for that.

Comment: Yes.I agree with David.in some codes use form variable before complete create itself.

Answer (score 5):

*(I added this answer, because IMHO others where not complete)*

Method 2 is the correct one.

Method 1 if never to be called, since there is an hidden parameter to the constructor call, which may fail proper iniatialize: in fact, `NewInstance` is a per-class pseudo virtual method!

In fact, there is an hidden `boolean` parameter at constructor call (register `EDX`, since `EAX`=class). As stated by [official documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Program_Control):

> Constructors and destructors use the same calling conventions as other
>   methods, except that an additional `Boolean` flag parameter is passed to
>   indicate the context of the constructor or destructor call.
>
> A value of `False` in the flag parameter of a constructor call indicates that the constructor was invoked through an instance object
>   or using the inherited keyword. In this case, the constructor behaves
>   like an ordinary method. A value of `True` in the flag parameter of a
>   constructor call indicates that the constructor was invoked through a
>   class reference. In this case, the constructor creates an instance of
>   the `class` given by `Self`, and returns a reference to the newly created
>   object in `EAX`.

In particular, when called that way, the class won't call the `_ClassCreate` function. It may fail to initialize the class, if the class is not to be created with the default `NewInstance` function. In fact, this function is inserted into the class VMT: in some rare cases, it may be overloaded (e.g. to provide another memory allocation pattern - may be a garbage collector or some speed-optimized allocator). So calling directly `InstanceClass.NewInstance` can be buggy, in some border cases.

```
function _ClassCreate(AClass: TClass; Alloc: Boolean): TObject;
asm
  ...
    TEST    DL,DL
    JL      @@noAlloc
    CALL    dword ptr [EAX].vmtNewInstance
@@noAlloc:
  ...
```

Therefore, calling `InstanceClass.NewInstance` directly is only to be done on purpose, only if you want to cancel two overridden `vmtNewInstance / vmtFreeInstance` (and in this case, you may have to also NOT call `.Free / .Destroy`, but you own memory free function). So: never call `NewInstance`, but the `constructor`, as designed and documented by Embarcadero (and *FreePascal* team by the way), unless you need to make some internal low-level tweak.

NEVER use method 1 to create an object! It may work 99.9 % of the time, but may fail some cases, or with a compiler/RTL enhancement in the future (like a garbage collector). Even if the VCL sometimes uses `NewInstance`, you should not use it - I would rather prefer this method to be made protected.

Comment: Using NewInstance will ignore an overridden "AfterConstruction" method, and this is one reason the instance may fail to initialize as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Second is better because it is a standard method to create a class instance, while procedural form should be used within constructor to call inherited constructor.

Comment: but built-in delphi method(Application.CreateForm) use InstanceClass.NewInstance

Comment: I agree with David, for some reason a reference to form instance is needed before the form constructor ends, though I can't say what the reason is.